# Xamarin imagesets not importing

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am trying to move a project from xcode to xamarin. The project uses a storyboard and images.xcassets to organise the images.
When I add the images to the Resources folder and try to open the storyboard for editing none of the images are showing or accessible from within xcode/interface builder.
I have also tried to add image assets through xamarin rather than straight out of XC with the same result.

All the images work when we import them flat to the Resources folder i.e not in an imageset or .xcassets folder they just don't when in imagesets

The rough structure I am after is:

[image]

In this example the image long_line is not available in the storyboard when opened.

Anyone else had this issue or know a way around it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reported this issue at [Bugzilla-Xamarin](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17271).

Issue seemed to be the addin component of Xamarin Studio was not synchronising asset files with the temporary Xcode project files. This has been resolved with **Xamarin Studio 4.2.3**

Comment: Saw the bug report. I can confirm that this does seem to be working in 4.2.3.

Comment: Upon further inspection the fix has its own problems. Although I can see the images in interface builder now I am unable to build a clean version of the project as I am getting an empty path warning.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the latest (today, i.e. [4.0.13](http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_4.0/xamarin.studio_4.0#13)) Xamarin Studio as many of the new (iOS7) [features](http://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-studio-and-ios-7/) introduced in Xcode5 are only available in this version.

There's a blog post (and video) about the new features available [here](http://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-studio-and-ios-7/).

Note that it's fairly new so there might be a few bugs lurking. If you find any please report them into [bugzilla](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have already seen the link about the assets and it works as they say when building. However, when opening the storyboard for editing none of the images are imported so all the images show as question marks which makes it a little tricky to alter etc. I'll file it as a bug and press on.